How max_background_compactions in RocksDB DBench affects Compaction Stats (L0'Rnp1)?
I run rocksdb db_bench with configurations
dbench --benchmarks="fillrandom,stats" --max_background_compactions=1 --num=100000000 --key_size=24 --value_size=1000 

and
dbench --benchmarks="fillrandom,stats" --max_background_compactions=8 --num=100000000 --key_size=24 --value_size=1000 

While runs db_bench with configuration of max_background_compactions=1, the Rnpl(GB) of L0 is 0.
But Rnpl(GB) of L0 is 76.0GB with configuration of max_background_compactions=8.
The full version of max_background_compactions=1 output: 
The full version of max_background_compactions8 output: 
It is confused because the define of Rnpl is Bytes read from level N+1 during compaction between levels N and N+1 in https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Compaction-Stats-and-DB-Status.
